# BigQuery timestamp display .9999

Tags: sql, csv, google-bigquery, timestamp

I recently uploaded a CSV file from GoogleSheets to BigQuery. The schemas are all correct, but there is an issue on the TIMESTAMP data.

The timestamp in the source file is every minute ends with 30 seconds. But when I uploaded it into BigQuery it became 29.999 secs one cell every three rows.

For example, source(4/12/2016 2:49:30) BigQuery(2016-04-12 00:01:59.999999 UTC).

Can somebody tell me what went wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in Google Sheets might look like it is every thirty seconds.  But it would seem to have a microseconds component, which is the issue you are seeing.  You could fix the problem in the Google Sheet using the `round()` function.

Or fix it in BigQuery using the expression:

```
timestamp_trunc(timestamp_add(col, interval 500 millisecond), second)
```

This adds half a second and then truncates the result.